Elementor preview not same as edit mode
I know this is an issue others have raised.  I've tried all suggestions - generate CSS, clear caches etc.
I my specific case I am working on two pages - an English version and an Arabic version.  I am using a custom carousel widget from the theme. With the English page I have no problems.  But for the Arabic page I have problems when under addtional css I set 'direction: rtl'. Then using the custom widget only the last 2 out of 6 items are displayed in the carousel and the direction of rotation is unchanged - in both edit and view mode.
I looked at the html generated - all 6 items were listed not just the two displayed, but there was an attribute on the 'div' containing the carousel: data-rtl="false".  There is no option on the widget to set this. So I took all the html for the carousel, changed the attribute to data-rtl="true" and pasted that in to wordpress, instead of using the widget.  And that was fine IN EDIT MODE.  All items were displayed in the carousel and it rotated in the required direction.
However, in the preview nothing is displayed.  The carousel is completely missing.  It does not matter what values I set for 'direction' under additional css or the values I set for data-rtl in the html: the html displays correctly only in edit mode - and the custom widget does not work in any case with 'direction: rtl' so it seems I need to use the html.
I'm new to wordpress and elementor but I used this trick on another page - editing and pasting in the html to translate the prompts on a custom form widget to Arabic. So I know it can/should work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Try adding this CSS to your page:
.custom-carousel .slick-list {
    direction: rtl;
}


Thanks.  I tried but wherever and however I tried setting this the carousel only displayed with direction ltr.  I'll use a different widget and some additional setup as a workaround to achieve what I want.
